# Проблема в присвоении стиля классу

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS, нужно сравнить 2 свойства и присвоить классу ширину в зависимости от условия, не могу понять почему не работает, вроде свойства display считывает, а ширину присваивать не хочет.

```
var ads1 = document.getElementById('ads-1');
var ads2 = document.getElementById('ads-2');

 if(window.getComputedStyle(ads1).display == "block")&&(window.getComputedStyle(ads2).display == "block")
 {
     var cl = document.getElementsByClassName('center');
    for(var i=0; i<cl.length; i++){i.style.width = "860px";}
 }
 else
 {
     var cl = document.getElementsByClassName('center');
    for(var i=0; i<cl.length; i++){i.style.width = "660px";}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты немного в коде запутался. Поменяй это

```
i.style.width = "860px;";
```

на это

```
cl[i].style.width = "860px;";
```

А то ты пытаешься ширину присвоить переменной `i` :D

Comment: да, тупанул, ведь массив же ))   ещё условие в одни скобки надо объединить, чтоб на && не ругался :)

Comment: @DaVASrK, странно. Тогда попробуй после каждой строки твоего кода написать строки `Console.log("hi 1");`, `Console.log("hi 2");`.. и так далее, чтобы понять, где код работать перестаёт. Скажи мне, что в консоли потом выведено будет.

Comment: Короче говоря отладку кода сделать надо

Comment: Всё сделал, спасибо, надо отдыхать, а то глупые ошибки к вечеру делаю